# New to mySQL and getting a syntax error

Tags: mysql

I'm getting a syntax error on line 2 when I enter this query. Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

```
Select Postcode, Lat, Lon, 
       acos(sin(:lat)*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos(:lat)*cos(radians(Lat))*cos(radians(Lon)-:lon)) * :R As D
From zips 
Where acos(sin(:lat)*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos(:lat)*cos(radians(Lat))*cos(radians(Lon)-:lon)) * :R < :rad
```

Comment: What is the error displayed?

Comment: If it was me, I'd wrap the distance stuff up in a tidy function.

Comment: what is the error ? Please post your error.

Answer (score 0):

How are you executing that statement? Are :lat and :lon stored procedure variables? I believe colon is what Oracle uses for bind variables but isn't valid syntax in MySQL.